# Как сделать, чтобы после запятой шла одна цифра?

Tags: java

Есть метод, который возвращает тип `double`, к примеру `3.13141` и тд.

Как его округлить, чтобы он возвращал только `3.1` или `3.2` и тд?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть веские основания подозревать, что вам надо число не хранить округлённым, а выводить. Тогда вам в раздел документации с говорящим названием "[Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)":

```
String formated = String.format("%.1f", Math.PI);
```

Comment: Именно это !Как вы поняли ?)Спасибо пойду почитаю !!!!!!!

Comment: Нет я его секундой до вас отметил )Благодарю!

Comment: Главное чтобы при этом вывод не превратился в `3,1` из-за использовании default-ой `Locale`.

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
double value = 3.7862132;
double newValue = Math.round(value*10.0)/10.0;
```

Comment: Благодарю! большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ну прям вот ой.

```
round(3.13141, 1); // returns 3.1

public static double round(double value, int position) {
    long dec1 = (long) Math.pow(10, position);
    value = value * dec1;
    long r = Math.round(value);
    return (double) r / dec1;
}
```

Comment: И правда ой, компилятор скажет `cannot find symbol`.

Comment: Черт, и точно ой, это же моя функция :) виноват. Нашел код, добавил. Писал ее так давно, что был уже уверен, что это что-то встроенное в java

Comment: Спасибо за совет и помощь

Comment: Не знаю насчет "ваша" - уж больно смахивает на функцию из [этого ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2808648/3432401) вплоть до отступов. Только некоторым переменные другие имена даны.